# Mounting a single partition dd image in macOS?

Tags: command-line, disk-utility, partition, mount

Using `testdisk`, I have made what is apparently a `dd` image of a single HFS+ partition (what was originially `/dev/disk1s2`, I think).

Now I try to mount this image file, but seemingly I cannot - even if `file` recognizes it as a HFS partition:

```
me@my-iMac:~$ hdiutil attach -imagekey diskimage-class=CRawDiskImage -nomount /Volumes/Test/image.dd 
/dev/disk2                                              

me@my-iMac:~$ hdiutil mount /dev/disk2 
hdiutil: mount failed - no mountable file systems

me@my-iMac:~$ hdiutil imageinfo /Volumes/Test/image.dd 
hdiutil: imageinfo failed - image not recognized

me@my-iMac:~$ file /Volumes/Test/image.dd 
/Volumes/Test/image.dd: Macintosh HFS Extended version 4 data (mounted) last mounted by: 'HFSJ', created: Wed Jul  4 14:32:40 2018, last modified: Thu Jul 19 09:07:22 2018, last checked: Wed Jul  4 10:32:40 2018, block size: 8192, number of blocks: 366241334, free blocks: 365063585
```

Is it possible to somehow mount this partition image in macOS/OSX as read/write?

Comment: Did you try renaming image.dd to image.img and double-clicking on it?

Comment: Thanks @pixelomer - didn't try that, though previously I did try renaming to `image.dmg`; the result is the same for double-clicking either `image.dmg` or `image.img`: I get a window, saying: "Warning; The following disk images couldn't be opened; Image: image.img; Reason: no mountable file systems"

Comment: I think image's filesystem is corrupted

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't answer the exact question, but the following has worked for me to mount a dd msdos image as read-only (`-o ro`).

```
$ hdiutil attach -nomount /Users/sunknudsen/Desktop/boot-clean.img
/dev/disk2

$ mkdir -p ~/Desktop/boot-clean
$ mount -o ro -t msdos /dev/disk2 ~/Desktop/boot-clean
```